c# interop excel: Write values to a range that is not continuous
I need to set values in an Excel sheet row by row. The cells where I'm setting the values are not necessarily following each other. So, instead of e.g. setting range "A2:C2" I may have to set non-continuous range "A2;B2;F2".
When the range is continuous, my code is working perfectly. But, when the range is non-continuous, so the cells in the range are not successive, all cells belonging to the range get the first value of my value array.
I have tried quite many different ways to create the range. Currently I'm using _Application.Union method to combine my ranges.
My code example:
var excelApp = worksheet.Application;
var Range1 = Sheet.get_Range("A2");
var Range2 = Sheet.get_Range("B2");
var Range3 = Sheet.get_Range("F2");

var combinedRange = excelApp.Union(Range1, Range2, Range3);

object[,] rangeDataObj = new object[1,3];

rangeDataObj[0,0] = "Value A2";
rangeDataObj[0,1] = "Value B2";
rangeDataObj[0,2] = "Value F2";

combinedRange.Value = rangeDataObj;

What I get after this on Excel sheet is that all cells A2 and B2 have correct values "Value A2" and "Value B2", but F2 has value "Value A2". But when the range consists of cells "A2;B2;C2", all cells get the value I want.
Why doesn't the non-continuous range get correct values and how to fix that? For performance reasons I don't want to use separate ranges for every cell.

What you got is multi-area range. combinedRange.Areas.Count in your case returns 2. It seems like it's simply not possible to get or set values the way you want it for noncontiguous ranges. The interop docs says:

You cannot set or get a noncontiguous range of cells in the XML spreadsheet format.

VBA docs are more specific:

Assigning an array to a multi-area range is not properly supported and should be avoided.

So it just doesn't work. You can get single cell objects, iterate them and assign values. Something like this:
    var ws = (Worksheet)Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    var range1 = ws.Range["A2:B2"];
    var range2 = ws.Range["F2:H2"];
    var range3 = ws.Range["A4"];

    var combinedRange = Application.Union(range1, range2, range3);

    string[] rangeDataObj = 
        [ "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5", "val6"];

    int idx = 0;
    foreach (var cell in combinedRange.Cast<Range>())
    { 
        cell.Value = rangeDataObj[idx++];
    }

